# Making/opening/writing files in nasm assembly mac x86_64, 64 bit not working

Tags: file, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am new to assembly and I wanted to get into writing files. I could not find anything for my conditions (64 bit on mac using nasm). Here is my code so far. Its not doing anything.

```
global start
; default rel
section .text
    start:
        mov rax, 0x2000005
        mov rdi, 2     
        mov rsi, file
        mov rdx, lenfile
        syscall

        mov rax, 0x2000001       ;Exiting
        xor rdi, rdi         
        syscall          

section .data
    
    file db "test.txt"
    lenfile equ $ - file
```

What can I change or add to make a file and write hello world on it?

EDIT 1

I know this will not work but this is what I have so far. I don't know how to write to the file. The file is not being created either.

```
global start
; default rel
section .text
    start:
        ;open
        mov rax, 0x2000005
        mov rdi, 2     
        mov rsi, file
        mov rdx, lenfile
        syscall
        ;write
        mov rax, 0x2000004
        mov rdi, 1     
        mov rsi, str
        mov rdx, strlen
        syscall
        ;close
        mov rax, 0x2000006
        mov rdi, 3     
        mov rsi, file
        ; mov rdx, lenfile
        syscall

        mov rax, 0x2000001       ;Exiting
        xor rdi, rdi         
        syscall          

section .data
    
    str: db "Hello world", 0
    strlen: equ $ - str
    file: db "test.txt"
    lenfile: equ $ - file
```

Edit 2

I think that I have properly opened it but now I need to properly close it. How would I do that. Forget the writing part for now. Here is what I have so far.

```
global start
; default rel
section .text
    start:
        ;open
        mov rax, 0x2000005
        mov rdi, file     
        mov rsi, 1   
        syscall
        
        ;close
        mov rax, 0x2000006
        mov rdi, file     
        mov rsi, 1
        
        syscall

        mov rax, 0x2000001       ;Exiting
        xor rdi, rdi         
        syscall          

section .data
    
    str: db "Hello world", 0
    strlen: equ $ - str
    file: db "test.txt"
    lenfile: equ $ - file
```

While I was writing edit 2, I looked at the c version on the closing part. It's just a simple function. `fclose(file);` How could I do that in assembly?

Comment: You need to first `open` the file and then `write` to it.  But I only see one file IO system call (I don't know the macos syscall numbers by heart so I don't know which one it is), so I can say that the code cannot work this way.

Comment: is 0x2000005 open? or is 0x2000008 open?

Comment: I don't know.  Refer to the documentation provided by your vendor (the system call numbers should be in the include file `sys/syscall.h`).

Comment: Okay I got it. 0x2000005 is open and 0x2000004 is write. I'll try to figure out a way to write TO the file.

Comment: Try to first implement it in C (using the functions `open()` and `write()`), then do the exact same thing in assembly.

Comment: I made an edit on the bottom. It's still not creating a file in assembly. I don't know how to write to that file and properly close it.

Comment: Read the documentation of the `open()` system call.  You can access it by typing `man 2 open` into a terminal.  What arguments does it take?  You need to provide the exact same arguments as you would provide in C.

Comment: Your `open` is calling the equivalent of `open(2, "test.txt", lenfile)` which makes no sense; it should be `open("test.txt", flags, perm)`.  So you need `mov rdi, file`, and then load `rsi` and `rdx` respectively with the appropriate flag and permission values (look up the flag bits in the system headers, permissions are the usual 0777 Unix bits).  Then the file descriptor will be returned in `rax` and that's what you need to pass in `rdi` to `write`.  Currently you are ignoring the returned value and just writing to fd 1 (standard output) all the time.

Comment: I think that I have properly opened it but now I need to properly close it. How would I do that? While I was writing edit 2, I looked at the c version. Its just a simple function. ```fclose(file);``` How could I do that in assembly?

Comment: I did a bit of research. It showed that I needed to get something called a file handle and then put it in rdi and then it will properly close. How can I get the file handle?

Comment: @DanielYoffdan You can get a file handle with the `open` system call which is identical to the C function `open()`.  It's called “file descriptor” in UNIX terminology.